# Terraform local provider Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider

I downloaded Terraform recently and now I'm trying to practice on my local machine, hence the need for me to use the hashicorp/local as provider. However, after creating a simple local.tf file in my terraform-local-file directory and running `terraform init` as root, I get an error.

This is my local.tf file.

```
resource "local_file" "love" {
  filename="/root/love.txt"
  content="I love Jesus Christ, because He first loved me."
}
terraform {
  required_providers {
    local = {
      source = "hashicorp/local"
      version = "2.3.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
}
```

This is the error I got:

```
root@OZIRICHIGO41022-wsl:~/terraform-local-file# terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/local...
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
│ hashicorp/local: could not connect to registry.terraform.io: Failed to request
│ discovery document: Get
│ "https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json": dial tcp: lookup
│ registry.terraform.io on 172.25.48.1:53: read udp
│ 172.25.53.6:53112->172.25.48.1:53: i/o timeout
```

Now, I have tried getting answers from [Hashicorp's website](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/5511799316243-Error-Failed-to-query-available-provider-packages), but I could not fully understand how to implement the suggested solutions provided there. So please let your answer be beginner-friendly because I'm just starting to learn Terraform and quite new to tech altogether. I'll appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

Comment: You must be behind a proxy

Comment: This is most likely a temporary network issue, either in your local firewall, or with connection from firewall to terraform registry website. Switch to different network or try to disable firewall and re-try.

Comment: Thank you @Technowise. I tried working with vscode instead of my WSL and there was no error. Then when I tried again with WSL it worked.